# Do individual atoms have any semblance of rotation (aka yaw, pitch, rol)?

Tags: rotation, atoms

When describing a static 3d object in 3d space, we often use 6 numbers: x, y, z coordinates of one of objects points and yaw, pitch, rol for objects rotation. Do individual atoms have any semblence of rotation in 3d space (probabilistic perhaps)?

Comment: It sounds like you might be thinking about atoms classically. Quantum mechanics changes things. You might look up the Stern-Gerlach experiment

Answer (score 0):

An atom whose total angular momentum is zero (that is, its [term symbol](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Term_symbol) is $^1S_0$) is not orientable.

If an atom's angular momentum is nonzero, you can choose some preferred direction (say, the direction of the local magnetic field) and say how strongly the atom's angular momentum $\vec J$ is aligned with field.  Note that both $\vec J$ and its projection onto your favorite axis, usually called $J_z$, are quantized.  If the number of electrons is even, the allowed total $J$ are non-negative integers, $J \in 0,1,2,\cdots$, and the allowed projections are integers $-J \leq J_z \leq J$.  If the number of electrons is odd, the unpaired electron's spin forbids $J=0$, and instead the allowed values are half-integers, $J\in \frac12, \frac32, \frac52, \cdots$.

For three degrees of freedom (roll, pitch, yaw) you would like to know the projection on all three axes, $J_z, J_x, J_y$.  However, those projection operators are [non-commuting observables](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Uncertainty_principle) and are therefore subject to the uncertainty principle. Since the uncertainty product $\sigma_{J_z} \sigma_{J_x} \gt 1/2$, for a $J=1$ system you basically can choose one axis to get information about, and doom yourself to complete ignorance about the projections on the other axes.  For high-spin systems you can recover some useful information about the orientation of the spin axis in three dimensions.

Note that the term symbol describes the angular momentum of the *electrons*. It's possible to have an atom whose electrons are orientable but whose spin-zero nucleus is not, or vice-versa.